# When to enable application load balancers on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I have an app launched on AWS ELB at the moment. AWS automatically enables an application load balancer which is a significant cost driver to my application. I only have 20 users at the moment, so the load on my application is quite low. When is a good time to enable load balancing?

Comment: what services that you use that cause load balancer to be enabled?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk on a T2.small EC2 instance.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk will always have a load balancer enabled. if you don't want to use a load balancer, deploy your application manually on an EC2 instance with Elastic IP

Comment: There is an option in ELB settings to switch from a load balanced application to a single instance type. Is this not doing what I think it is?

Comment: ah... yes... I forgot about that. you can use single instance environment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html#single-instance-environ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single instance environment in Elastic Beanstalk if you don't want to use load balancer yet.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html#single-instance-environ

Quote:

> Single-instance environment
>
> A single-instance environment contains one Amazon EC2 instance with an
> Elastic IP address. A single-instance environment doesn't have a load
> balancer, which can help you reduce costs compared to a load-balanced,
> scalable environment. Although a single-instance environment does use
> the Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling service, settings for the minimum number
> of instances, maximum number of instances, and desired capacity are
> all set to 1. Consequently, new instances are not started to
> accommodate increasing load on your application.
>
> Use a single-instance environment if you expect your production
> application to have low traffic or if you are doing remote
> development. If you're not sure which environment type to select, you
> can pick one and, if required, you can switch the environment type
> later. For more information, see Changing environment type.